# Modal needs to have a 5 second timer and redirect after

Tags: javascript

I am using this code

```
    // Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

I want to be able add the ability to insert a 5 second counter into it like this:

```
var counter = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    counter++;
    // Display 'counter' wherever you want to display it.
    if (counter == 5) {
        // Display a login box
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 1000);
```

and after that countdown have the page redirect if they dont click to close with this:

```
setTimeout(function () {
   //Redirect with JavaScript
   window.location.href= 'http://thisinterestsme.com/php-forcing-https-over-http/';
}, 5000);
```

How can I combine these?

Comment: Just move your `window.location` where your `clearInterval` is now?

Comment: Is there a reason for using an interval? Otherwise you could just do it like `setTimout(function () { window.location = '...' }, 5000)` and remove the interval itself. Edit: That is already what you are doing :P

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

A "recursive" function with `setTimeout`:

```js
var counter = 0;
var interval = function() {

  setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(counter++);
      if (counter == 5) {
          console.log("redirect");
      } else {
        interval();
      }
  }, 1000);
};


interval();
```